# EntityFramework: Add Where clause to ObjectSet Query to Select on CHILD attributes

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

The goal is to return a list of PARENT entities, based on attributes of their CHILD ENTITIES

eg Find me all the CASTLES where LADIES_IN_WAITING belong to PRINCESS 'X'

I want to do something like this:

```
var query = ObjectSet.Include(c => c.LADIES_IN_WAITING);
query = query.Where(p => p.REGION.ToLower().Contains("shrekVille"));
query = query.Where(p => p.LADIES_IN_WAITING.Where(c => c.PRINCESS.Equals("fiona")));
var results = query.ToList();
```

This is obviously the incorrect syntax but i can't find any clear examples of how to structure the Query.

I am currently resorting to something like this:

```
var query = ObjectSet.Include(c => c.LADIES_IN_WAITING);
query = query.Where(p => p.REGION.ToLower().Contains("shrekVille"));

// Get the results from the DB using the query built thus far
var results = query.ToList();

// Now filter the list in memory manually
foreach (var castle in results)
{
    var matchingParents = new List<CASTLE>();
    var matchingChildren = castle.LADIES_IN_WAITING.Where(a => a.PRINCESS.Equals("fiona"));
    if (matchingChildren.Count() > 0) 
        matchingParents.Add(matchingChild);
}
results = matchingParents;
```

Any suggestions on how to correctly build the Query would be most welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the [`Any` operator](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/AnyOperator.ashx). It returns true if one item in a collection (i.e. 'any' of them) satisfies the predicate.

```
var query = ObjectSet.Include(c => c.LADIES_IN_WAITING); 
query = query.Where(p => p.REGION.ToLower().Contains("shrekVille")); 

// filter the query where, for each p, 
// any of the LADIES_IN_WAITING have PRINCESS.Equals("fiona") == true
query = query.Where(p => p.LADIES_IN_WAITING.Any(c => 
    c.PRINCESS.Equals("fiona"))); var results = query.ToList();
```

The complementary operator is `All`, which would filter your query to those results that have *all* the LADIES_IN_WAITING meeting the `PRINCESS.Equals("fiona")` criteria.

Comment: @Hellspawn Feel free to upvote this answer is it was helpful :)

Comment: Sorry Kirk...i did try but i don't have the power! (Need 15 Reputation to up vote)